# Return NSURLConnection data from class

Tags: ios, objective-c, class, variables, methods

I have am NSURLConnection to get a JSON value from my web server. The code is placed in a class which can be called from other UIViewControllers.

I am a little unsure on how to return the JSON data from the class however.

Here is what I have tried:
    +(NSJSONSerialization *) getTask:(id)task_id{

```
    NSJSONSerialization *json;

    NSLog(@"task id = %@", task_id);

    NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"&task_id=%@", task_id];

    NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
    NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.iampeterstuart.co.uk/todo/index.php/task/get"]]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Current-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody:postData];

    NSURLConnection *conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:YES];

    [conn start];

    return json;
}

// Log the response for debugging
+ (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
    NSLog(@"Resonse: %@", response);
}
+ (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data {
    NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSJSONSerialization *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
}

// Declare any connection errors
+ (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}
```

Each time the variable `json` is null?

Could somebody please advice?

Many thanks,

Peter

Comment: How to: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch37.html#_http_requests

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are thinking incorrectly about the delegate's behavior.

`(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data` will be called whenever new data is available (downloaded from the server), which is the raw bytes of the byte stream. You should have an instance of `NSMutableData` and append that received data to the mutable data when data is received. Finally, when the whole data (e.g. JSON string in your example) is downloaded, `-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection` will be called. In that method, you should parse the JSON string:

```
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSData *jsonData = [jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSJSONSerialization *json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:nil];
```

...where `data` is the cumulative data received. You can create the data instance as below in the class implementation:

```
NSMutableData *cumulativeData;
```

In `init` or whatever method that is initially called on your delegate before you start loading, call:

```
cumulativeData = [NSMutableData data];
```

Then in your `(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data` method, call:

```
[cumulativeData appendData:data];
```

That should append the received data into the cumulative data that you are "building".

Comment: `didReceiveResponse:` is called earlier. You mean `connectionDidFinishLoading:`

Comment: I am a little confused. What should I do with NSMutableData?

Comment: I've added some more code examples to clarify the process, let me know if you have any other suggestions.

Comment: I managed to figure it out myself, but thanks. I have accepted your answer :)